# How to replace <br /> with a carriage return so it displays in a textarea properly?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am using this code to get in a textarea value on my form:

```
EncodeForHTML(REReplaceNoCase(Trim(Form.Description), '\r', '<br />', 'all'))
```

It is simply replacing all carriage returns (new line) in the textarea with an HTML tag of `<br />`. It then HTML encodes this before inserting into the database.

When I want to display the textarea value back into a text area I am doing this:

```
<textarea>#Canonicalize(Description, true, true)#</textarea>
```

All its doing is Canonicalizing/Decoding the HTML value into a proper readable format.

The problem I have is that the textarea shows the `<br />` as part of the string in the text box area. I don't want it to show this because its not part of the description string. Its just indicating a new line.

How could I fix this so that the `<br />` in the string is translated into a carraige return for the textarea to display the contents properly?

Comment: I think replacing the `\r` was wrong. Instead I did it as suggested by Xevi like this `EncodeForHTML(ReplaceNoCase(Trim(Form.Description), Chr(13) & Chr(10), '<br />', 'all'))` and it works fine. It displays the correct `<br />` when using the value on standard HTML page, and it also shows the carriage returns when using it in a textarea.

Comment: (Edit) Yes. There is no reason `REReplaceNoCase` would not work with `\r`, unless the content did not actually contain carriage returns. Most likely it was a new line instead ie `\n`, and that is why the original code did not work. That is where it helps to examine the ascii values of each character. Just to determine *which* white space character you are dealing with (the human eye is terrible with white space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace your `<br />` with `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`.

As described in the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_04.html):

- `Chr(10)` returns a linefeed character
- `Chr(13)` returns a carriage return character
- The two-character string `Chr(13) & Chr(10)` returns a Windows newline

Comment: I replaced the `Chr(13) & Chr(10)` with `<br />` instead of replacing `\r` with `<br />` and it all works perfectly! thank you so much